# Source file '' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have some solution already created I need to work with, but I get these:

```
Warning 1   At least one file is missing the 'RelPath' attribute.   SolutionName

Error   2   Source file '' could not be found   C:\Users\me\Desktop\someDir\someDir\CSC SolutionName
```

I use VS Express 2013 for Desktop.
I get this error when I click rebuild solution

Why I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Post the code. Explain what file you are loading. Explain where the file is located. This question is formulated badly.

Comment: It is a fairly complex solution of one project containing few hundred classes in 10 - 15 namespaces, including few libraries, 50000+ lines of code, post what exactly?

Comment: @justanothercoder when you post a question, imagine someone who knows nothing about your project details. Than try to describe your problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create a backup of your project file.

In solution explorer, right click your project and unload it. Then right click again and "Edit project file".

There you can inspect your files. There should be a problem with one of them, like lacking a file name, or something different from the other files.
Remove the attributes regarding that file, save the project, right click, reload project.

Comment: it worked windows 11 office 365 visual studio 2022 c#

Comment: Restarting VS worked for me